# Drupal 7 relative image path are prefixed with module name

Tags: image, drupal

I wrote a module for Drupal 7 which is working fine on localhost.

When I upload the module, the path of each image of the module are not the same than on localhost : they are prefixed with the language (fr/) and then with the name of the module (in my case agilitag/)

So the link to the pictures are broken because I have as full path
http://www.agilitag.com/fr/agilitag/sites/all/modules/agilitag/images/edit.png
in place of
http://www.agilitag.com/sites/all/modules/agilitag/images/edit.png

I can't find on internet how to remove or adapt the path to the images correctly

Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add a "/" before each of my relative link and it worked with clean urls activated